# How to display popup dialog after app start?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, dialog, qml

If i use the `PopupUtils.open()` command in the `Component.onCompleted` property of the any item it does nothing, example:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    height: 600
    width: height
    Component.onCompleted: {
        PopupUtils.open(dialog, rect)
        }

    Component {
         id: dialog
         Dialog {
             id: dialogue
             title: "Save file"
             text: "Are you sure that you want to save this file?"
             Button {
                 text: "cancel"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
             Button {
                 text: "overwrite previous version"
                 color: "orange"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
             Button {
                 text: "save a copy"
                 color: "orange"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
         }
    }
```

how can i properly display a popup dialog just after the app has started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, it works using a `Timer`, ie:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    height: 600
    width: height
    Component.onCompleted: {
        start_timer.start()
     }

    Timer {
        id: start_timer
        interval: 200;
        onTriggered: PopupUtils.open(dialog, rect)
    }

    Component {
         id: dialog
         Dialog {
             id: dialogue
             title: "Save file"
             text: "Are you sure that you want to save this file?"
             Button {
                 text: "cancel"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
             Button {
                 text: "overwrite previous version"
                 color: "orange"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
             Button {
                 text: "save a copy"
                 color: "orange"
                 onClicked: PopupUtils.close(dialogue)
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PopupUtils.Open(dialog, id) is meant to wok for buttons.

Hence, add a button with the visible property as false and pass the id of that hidden button in place of "id" above (Without quotation of course).

Source:

> Had the same problem :)